# How can we fit a closed curve?

Tags: fitting, data

```
Data={{15., -9.8861}, {14., -9.80713}, {13., -9.60669}, {12., -9.37226}, \
{11., -9.56058}, {10., -9.52826}, {9., -9.3295}, {8., -9.16436}, {7., \
-9.04076}, {6., -8.89642}, {5., -9.46254}, {4., -9.5109}, {3., \
-8.90791}, {2., -8.09209}, {1., -8.54887}, {0., -7.93869}, {0., \
-7.93869}, {-1., -6.92529}, {-2., -6.48322}, {-3., -5.36115}, {-4., \
-2.29101}, {-5., 1.52439}, {-6., 4.79197}, {-7., 7.2295}, {-8., 
  8.29515}, {-9., 9.19184}, {-10., 9.39874}, {-11., 9.56396}, {-12., 
  9.88203}, {-13., 9.62128}, {-14., 9.84259}, {-15., 9.89896}, {-15., 
  9.89896}, {-14., 9.81998}, {-13., 9.61955}, {-12., 9.38511}, {-11., 
  9.57344}, {-10., 9.54112}, {-9., 9.34235}, {-8., 9.17722}, {-7., 
  9.05361}, {-6., 8.90928}, {-5., 9.47539}, {-4., 9.52376}, {-3., 
  8.92076}, {-2., 8.10495}, {-1., 8.56173}, {0., 7.95154}, {0., 
  7.95154}, {1., 6.93814}, {2., 6.49608}, {3., 5.374}, {4., 
  2.30386}, {5., -1.51154}, {6., -4.77912}, {7., -7.21664}, {8., \
-8.28229}, {9., -9.17899}, {10., -9.38589}, {11., -9.55111}, {12., \
-9.86918}, {13., -9.60843}, {14., -9.82973}, {15., -9.8861}};    

ListPlot[Data]
```

[image]

This is my try

```
fitFunc = 
  Total@Table[
    a[i] Tanh[b[i] x + c[i]] + d[i] Tanh[e[i] x - f[i]], {i, 1, 1}];
params = Flatten@
   Table[{a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i], f[i]}, {i, 1, 1}];

nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[Data, fitFunc, params, x];
Plot[{nlm1[t]}, {t, -15, 15}]
```

[image]

Comment: Define what you mean by 'closed shape profile'? Your code only has a curve, not a shape with area.

Comment: @flinty, you are right it is a curve

Comment: This looks like a classical hysteresis curve. I would separately fit its upper and lower parts.

Comment: Consider [ListCurvePathPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html) and [FindCurvePath](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html). There is also the resource function [CurveToBSpline](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CurveToBSplineFunction/). I would test them if you copy pasted the list of points in the question. I do not want to access a Dropbox account.

Comment: Thanks @userrandrand, data is updated

Comment: Good observation by @AlexeiBoulbitch and if the data is really the result of a hysteresis process, then there's also a 3rd variable you haven't mentioned.  Are the 64 data points taken equally spaced?   Also, the first and last data points are exactly equal.  Is that by design or coincidence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do the same you did but twice for each half of the data.

```
dat = {{15., -9.8861}, {14., -9.80713}, {13., -9.60669}, {12., \
-9.37226}, {11., -9.56058}, {10., -9.52826}, {9., -9.3295}, {8., \
-9.16436}, {7., -9.04076}, {6., -8.89642}, {5., -9.46254}, {4., \
-9.5109}, {3., -8.90791}, {2., -8.09209}, {1., -8.54887}, {0., \
-7.93869}, {0., -7.93869}, {-1., -6.92529}, {-2., -6.48322}, {-3., \
-5.36115}, {-4., -2.29101}, {-5., 1.52439}, {-6., 4.79197}, {-7., 
    7.2295}, {-8., 8.29515}, {-9., 9.19184}, {-10., 9.39874}, {-11., 
    9.56396}, {-12., 9.88203}, {-13., 9.62128}, {-14., 
    9.84259}, {-15., 9.89896}, {-15., 9.89896}, {-14., 
    9.81998}, {-13., 9.61955}, {-12., 9.38511}, {-11., 
    9.57344}, {-10., 9.54112}, {-9., 9.34235}, {-8., 9.17722}, {-7., 
    9.05361}, {-6., 8.90928}, {-5., 9.47539}, {-4., 9.52376}, {-3., 
    8.92076}, {-2., 8.10495}, {-1., 8.56173}, {0., 7.95154}, {0., 
    7.95154}, {1., 6.93814}, {2., 6.49608}, {3., 5.374}, {4., 
    2.30386}, {5., -1.51154}, {6., -4.77912}, {7., -7.21664}, {8., \
-8.28229}, {9., -9.17899}, {10., -9.38589}, {11., -9.55111}, {12., \
-9.86918}, {13., -9.60843}, {14., -9.82973}, {15., -9.8861}};
Data = dat[[1 ;; 32]];
fitFunc = 
  Total@Table[
    a[i] Tanh[b[i] x + c[i]] + d[i] Tanh[e[i] x - f[i]], {i, 1, 1}];
params = Flatten@
   Table[{a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i], f[i]}, {i, 1, 1}];

nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[Data, fitFunc, params, x];
Plot[{nlm1[t]}, {t, -15, 15}];

Data = dat[[33 ;; -1]];
fitFunc = 
  Total@Table[
    a[i] Tanh[b[i] x + c[i]] + d[i] Tanh[e[i] x - f[i]], {i, 1, 1}];
params = Flatten@
   Table[{a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i], f[i]}, {i, 1, 1}];

nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[Data, fitFunc, params, x];
Plot[{nlm1[t]}, {t, -15, 15}];
Show[%%%%%%, %]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice I did not know the data was already sorted

Answer (score 5):

We split the data set:

```
joinDS = Module[{a = SplitBy[Sort[Data], First]}, {a[[All, 1]], a[[All,2]]}];
```

We define the function:

```
branch[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a Tanh[b x + c]
```

and we fit the data using the [MultiNonlinearModelFit](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit/)

```
    fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][joinDS, {branch[x, a1, b1, c1], 
branch[x, a2, b2, c2]}, {a1, b1, c1,a2, b2, c2}, {x}, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

(you can see that the output involves the [Switch](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) function)

Here are the results:

```
Show[{ListPlot[Data], Plot[{fit[1, x], fit[2, x]}, {x, -15, 15}]}]
```

[image]

However, since we are talking about hysteresis I would go for these functions:

```
B1[h_, b_, s_, x_] := -s  Tanh[1/h ArcTanh[b/s] (x + h)];
B2[h_, b_, s_, x_] := -s  Tanh[1/h ArcTanh[b/s] (x - h)];
```

and I would fit it with the same fitting parameters (h,b,s):

```
  fit2 = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][joinDS, 
<|"Expressions" -> {B2[h, b, s, x], B1[h, b, s, x]}, "Constraints" -> h > 4 && b > 8 && s > 9|>, {h, b, s}, {x}]
```

Which gives:

```
Show[{ListPlot[Data], Plot[{fit2[1, x], fit2[2, x]}, {x, -15, 15}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This code is much simpler than mine. However, note that the parameters were not properly fit. In particular, with all parameters free, the fitted parameters to the upper branch are different from that of the lower branch, despite the data being the same. These are not real data, the points that make the lower branch are the reflection about the origin of those on the upper branch.

Answer (score 3):

The curve is difficult because of the noisy ends of the hysteresis. To see this consider ordering the points using [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html):

**Note :** `data` is `Data` in your list of points.

```
sorted = data[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[data];
```

We may plot these points:

[image]

The different colors represent different sections that `FindCurvePath` found. Notice multiple sections at the end suggesting that the noise there makes it difficult to find a path. You can remove those unwanted segmentations and study them separately. **I will only focus on the large part** to show some methods.

**Note:** You can directly use ListLinePlot[sorted[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odez1.png)]] and changed the `InterpolationOrder` option but because of the noise, interpolation should be avoided.

**Method 1 : Find Splines**

Here we use the resource function [CurveToBSplineFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CurveToBSplineFunction/) :

```
spline = ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"];
```

We can choose parameters using Manipulate although it can be a bit slow:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[
   spline[sorted[[2]], d, s, "CurveClosed" -> True][t], {t, 0, 1}], 
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]], {d, 1, 10, 2}, {s, 0.05, 1, 0.1}]
```

degree d=1 spline and scale s=0.05:

[image]

degree d=9 spline and scale s=0.85

[image]

**Method 2: Using machine learning separately on the ordered x and y coordinates**

**Note:** There is an issue at the boundary so you might not want to use this method although it has the advantage of not requiring parameter adjustments

Recalling that `sorted[[2]]` is the ordered data points in the middle, we can introduce a fictitious time with discrete values {1,2,...`Length[sorted[[2]]]`} and fit {x[t],t} and {y[t],t} and use a `ParametricPlot`. I imagine that the first method above does something similar internally.

With n the sized of the considered data (`sorted[[2]]`) we may create a list of data points `{{x[1],1},{x[2],2}....{x[n],n}},{{y[1],1},{y[2],2},...,{y[n],n}}` :

Note: ⎵=[UnderBracket]

```
parametric⎵data = 
  sorted[[2]] // Transpose // Map[Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #}] &];
```

In my limited experience fitting noisy data, [`Predict`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html) with the method GaussianProcess has given the nicest results. I learned about from an answer I found on stack exchange you may search for other examples if needed.

```
predict = 
  Predict[Rule @@@ #, Method -> "GaussianProcess", 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] & /@ parametric⎵data;
```

Plot and compare the fit with the data:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[Through[predict[x]], {x, 0, 35}], 
 ListPlot[sorted[[2]], PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Notice that the curve is not closed I do not know why.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an extended comment.

It appears that you really only have 32 data points rather than 64 data points so a description of how you constructed the data should be included in your question. Also, as I mentioned in a comment, if this is really a hysteresis loop, the third (but missing) variable that predicts both the "x" and "y" coordinate should be included.

Why do I think you only have 32 data points?  Consider the first 32 responses and the negative of the last 32 responses:

```
d1 = Data[[1 ;; 32, 2]];
d2 = -Data[[33 ;; 64, 2]];
ListPlot[{d1, d2}, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], {PointSize[0.0075], White}}]
```

[image: Plot of responses]

The differences in the two lists are essentially a constant:

```
d1 - d2
(* {0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01286, 0.01285, 
    0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01286, 
    0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01285, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01285, 
    0.01285, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01286, 0.01285, 0.01285, 0.01285, 
    0.01285, 0.01285, 0.01286, 0.01286} *)
```

That perfect fit doesn't happen with 64 real-life data points (even in physics).  So I think you really only have 32 data points.

Answer (score 2):

In order to warrant a closed curve, the parameters used in the two branches of the closed curve must be constrained.
I suggest the inclusion of another predictive variable to distinguish the two branches, and fit the parameters to all data simultaneously.
First, include the identification of the branch in the data:

```
dataC =
Join[Transpose[{data[[;;32,1]],ConstantArray["down",32], data[[;;32,2]]}],
Transpose[{data[[33;;,1]],ConstantArray["up",32], data[[33 ;; , 2]]} ] ]
```

Define the function

```
branch[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a Tanh[b  x + c]

fitFunc[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, direction_] :=
    Switch[direction, "up", branch[x, a, b, c], "down", branch[x, d, e, f] ]
```

Fit:

```
result =  NonlinearModelFit[dataC, fitFunc[t, a, b, c, a, e, f, dir], 
 {{a, -10}, {b, 0.3}, {c, -1}, {e, 0.3}, {f, 1.2}}, {t, dir} ]
```

Notice that a is repeated in fitFunc[ ] call, which imposes the constraint of equal amplitudes for the two branches of the curve.
Plot:

```
{af, bf, cf, ef, ff} = result["ParameterTableEntries"][[All, 1]]

Show[ ListPlot[{data[[33 ;;]], data[[;; 32]]}, PlotLegends ->{"up","down"}], 
      Plot[{fitFunc[x, af, bf, cf, af, ef, ff, "up"], 
         fitFunc[x, af, bf, cf, af, ef, ff, "down"]}, {x, -15, 15}, 
         PlotLegends -> {"up", "down"}]  ]
```

[image: the points are the data, the lines the model function with fitted parameters]

With real data, the parameters b and e will be different, as well as c and f. However, the constraint b == e can be imposed just changing e by b when calling fitFunc[ ]. If needed, the hypothesis that the curve is closed can be tested, just change one of the a's in fitFunc[ ] call by d, and providing an estimate to NonlinearModelFit.

Comment: Equivalent approach as the one presented by @Vito Vanin (i.e. using the Switch function) can be achieved using MultiNonlinearModelFit (https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit/) which uses the Switch command under the bonnet.

Comment: @demm You should post an answer based on MultiNonlinearModelFit[ ], which avoids all the chore of recasting the data, writing the Switch[ ], and constraining the parameters. It is the best answer for this question. From now on, I'll use it for constrained parameters fit.